# Adding infinite scroll to my RecycleView

Tags: android

I am trying to add infinite scroll to my RecyclerView.
I am fetching top 20 movies from tmdb, and when I scroll down I want them to reload again.

Right now i am getting these problems:

1.not suitable method found for getActivity()

2.can not find symbol variable spanCount.

Can somebody help me?
GIthub repo: https://github.com/adnxy/MyMovieApp

My code is bellow:

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), spanCount);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And infinite scroll:

> mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached

                Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");

                // Do something

                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where you are using `GridLayoutManager ` ?

Comment: Where do I need to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create three variable

```
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
```

After that create LayoutManager like this

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And in the last put Listner Like this

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        Log.w("RecyclerviewListner","Last Item Detected");
                    }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: postContainer and  if(isFinishedLoading) {  getPost(false); are red?

Comment: What can I do about that

Comment: @Adnxy remove it !! it is my variable to check loading data from server or notso remove it and put log over  there

Comment: Should i remove all postContainer.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()? thanks a lot:)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manifest. I still have problems with 1.st line of code postContainer. It is still red

Comment: can not resolve method getActivity(), do you know what is problem? and I get problems with closing brackets? Thanks bro!!!

Comment: @Adnxy  getActivity() will be useful if you are using fragment class if you are using in Activity class write YourActivity.this

Comment: mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);    Under MainActivity.this there is red and showing error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: do you know what is problem? @Manifest

Comment: do you know what is problem? @Manifest  Error: GridLayoutManager(context,int) is not applicable